# Report a map error on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does someone has any idea why the *Google Map* shows **Report a map error** on its right bottom ?

And let me know if this can be removed while initializing the map.

[image: Error on Right bottom => Report a map error]

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just pass the parameter **disableDefaultUI: true,** in the mapOptions and that will remove it.

Then you can add elements you want specifically (like the zoom control etc) by adding the following to mapOptions

**panControl: false,** 
**zoomControl: false,**
***scaleControl: true,***

You can refer to [Google Maps Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using disableDefaultUI doesn't remove it for me. Note that the report link availability is dependent on the map extent, i.e. it may or may not be shown for a particular country.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using CSS trick. It's dirty but working:

```
/* remove ugly google report-a-bug button from maps */
.gmnoprint:last-child {
    display: none !important;
}
```